# Accessing the Wordpress REST API from Drupal

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal

I have a Drupal website and a Wordpress website, and I have a single sign-on system setup, so the users exists in both website databases, with the Drupal site as the master. I would like to add some code that runs when I save a user in Drupal, and it will update the user in Wordpress using the REST API. I'm not sure how I would authenticate to connect with the REST API, any assistance would be appreciated. eg. Do I need to setup a specific Wordpress user for this purpose, and then I use this to make the REST API calls? Or is there another way that I can authenticate from the Drupal code?

Comment: please let us know what you have tried so far.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is a very long subject, there are some very cool tutorials on this I will leave some here as an example:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-creating-updating-and-deleting-data--cms-24883
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/rest-api-create-delete-posts.html
https://torquemag.io/2015/08/working-with-users-via-the-wordpress-rest-api/

And lastly I recommend you read the wordpress documentation, the above posts show how to authenticate to delete, post, edit posts and pages but the change of users is the same just need to use the endpoint and the necessary parameters you can find here in the documentation. from wordpress.

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/